# How do I customize the Marker popup with Mapbox for Android

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm building an Android application using the Mapbox Android SDK.  I'm adding markers to the map as shown below.  How can I customize the popup so that it can have a button that will call a navigation intent?

```
LayerData.LayerFeature feature = layerDataArray.get(i).features.get(j);
Marker m = new Marker(map, feature.name, feature.address1 
  + ", " + feature.address2 + ", " + feature.city + ", " + feature.state,
new LatLng(feature.lat, feature.lng));
m.setIcon(new Icon(this, Icon.Size.MEDIUM, 
  feature.marker_symbol, feature.marker_color));
map.addMarker(m);
locationItemArray.add(new LocationItem(layerDataArray.get(i).features.get(j).title, layerDataArray.get(i).features.get(j).description,
layerDataArray.get(i).features.get(j).lat, layerDataArray.get(i).features.get(j).lng));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   mapView.setOnMarkerClickListener(new MapView.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            materialDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar) {

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                }
            };
            materialDialog.show();
            materialDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @OsvaldoBringaz, edit your code and explain what was the error and I would be able to remove my down vote